# Refresh an Iframe Once Upon Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a cross browser iframe that is working minus one small detail. The initial frame load does not re-size all the way.  So items are cut off at the bottom of the screen.  It re-sizes perfectly if the frame is refreshed.

Is there a way to refresh an iframe once on the page load?

Example is here:

http://www.aans.org/aansmarketplace.aspx

goto multimedia products and select dvd.  You will notice content cut off at the bottom of the screen...but if you reload the frame all of the content shows.

Comment: Do you have access to the source of the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="empty_script.php" />
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#iframe").attr('src', 'your_Script.php');
});
</Script>
```

Comment: This will work fine unless you're going from http -> https, in which case you will get an obnoxious warning.

Answer (score 0):

How are you resizing the iframe? If you have access to iframe containing page use onload event of iframe, calculate the inner document height and set it to iframe. This works perfectly fine in all browser.